# ngRoute not working when page reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am using ngRoute to my application. problem is when i reload that page, there is an error. 
error said 
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngTable','jcs-autoValidate','ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/container-details', {
            templateUrl : 'container-details-test.jsp',
            controller  : 'myCtrl'

        })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Comment: You have to add some rewrite rules within your server config working with the HTML5 mode.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure your server based off the guidelines on this page:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode